# 2005- Unknown mysql server host'localhost'(0)

Tags: mysql

I was using navicat for mysql to connect to mysql 5.5.25,it usually show me this:2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost'(0).Currently my resolution is to turn up the network,then it return to normal.but when network is not up,it shows that error,I had searched a lot,but no answer is revalent to it.So,does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: what is OS platform ??  does mysql deamon or service running first verify it.  Check Netstat if port 3306 is listening or not

Comment: windows8.1 ，ｈｅｒｅ
 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:55074        ESTABLISHED     InHost

 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:55392        ESTABLISHED     InHost

 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:55393        ESTABLISHED     InHost

 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:56317        ESTABLISHED     InHost

 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:56329        ESTABLISHED     InHost

 TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:56403        ESTABLISHED     InHost

Comment: is localhost pinging ?? localhost is assumed as 127.0.0.1.  You can check where is mysql bin files.. you will fine mysql.exe file in it.. in `cmd` go to that path & hit `mysql -uusername -ppassword`

Comment: int cmd it can connects correctly,but when i use 'navicat for mysql' to set connections ,it shows the error above

Comment: Then You are typing something wrong in navicat or you might have firewall or other rules.. Try changing host address to 127.0.0.1 in navicat connection

Comment: You could try setting the DNS manually in C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts: `localhost 127.0.0.1`. (If the domain name resolution has some problem.) Or try a MySQL connection with `127.0.0.1`. I do not think that `(0)` indicates a port, but you might try an explicit port 3306.

Comment: when i hit ping 'localhost' in cmd,it shows:

Comment: pinging [::1] with 32 bytes of data

Comment: reply from ::1: time<1ms

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, but it only occurs when my computer is not on-line (for example when working on an airplane).   I just change the word 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1 and it seems to be working even when off-line.  I hope.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to create the linked server using studio and the various menus, a small detail is not saved in the connection string, which is the database! (see last bit of the connection string)

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='MYSQL',
   @srvproduct='MySQL',
       @provider='MSDASQL', @provstr='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1
       Driver};SERVER=HOST;Port=3306;USER=uid;PASSWORD=pw;OPTION=3;DATABASE=mydb';
```